# Is there a better way to write a "what key is this" question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

My understanding is that "what key is this chord progression" is not considered on topic/appropriate for this site ([Reducing occurences of "What key is this song in?"](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2258/reducing-occurences-of-what-key-is-this-song-in))

Does that mean that generally, any/all analysis questions of a specific song/progression/melody are simply dissuaded entirely? Or is there a better way to come at this that is better for the site?

As an author of a song who doesn't understand the theory behind what I've created, I thought best to ask rather than just post the question and get it closed.

Is this more relevant to chat for instance? Or simply not appropriate for Music.SE *at all* and I should look elsewhere?

Comment: In general a lot of discussion can happen in chat. I believe this answer if not covering everything at least links to a lot of the discussions that have gone on around this: https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2951/7222

Answer (score 2):

Instead of simple “what is this?" questions, a user could instead ask “how do I figure out what this is?”

For the example here, “How to determine the key of a piece of music?” is a much better fit for the site. There probably already are some questions related to that.

If a “how to” question is too broad, they can often be broken up into reasonable parts. Like, “how do I find the tonal center of a piece of music or passage?” and “how do I determine the mode of a passage or piece of music?”

Comment: All those questions have already been asked and answered.

Comment: @PiedPiper Perfect. All we have to do is mark as dupe and the askers will have their answers.